# Как правильно перевести массив из PHP в JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, массивы

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно перевести массив из **php** в **js** так, что бы внутри массива `order` создавались новые объекты, но при это не появлялись новые массивы, как показано в моём примере:

```
<?php
$credit=array(
    array('Товар 1','10','2000'),
    array('Товар N','N','N'),
    array('Товар 10','6','9000')
    );                                                                      
?>

var credit_m_m = <?php echo json_encode($credit_m_m);?>;                      

for (var i = 0; i <credit_m_m.length; i++) {                                  

var options = {                                                 
     manualInput: false,
     order:[{
            category: '235',
            model: credit_m_m[i][0],
            quanity: credit_m_m[i][1],
            price: credit_m_m[i][2]
},
{
            category: '235',
            model: credit_m_m[i][0],
            quanity: credit_m_m[i][1],
            price: credit_m_m[i][2]
},
{
            category: '235',
            model: credit_m_m[i][0],
            quanity: credit_m_m[i][1],
            price: credit_m_m[i][2]
          }]                                                                           
}                                                                          
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте ассоциативный массив

```
$credit=array(
    array(
    'name'=> 'tovar',
    'num'=> '10',
    'year'=> '2007',
    ),
    array(
    'name'=> 'tovar',
    'num'=> '10',
    'year'=> '2007',
    )
);
```

вернет массив объектов

```
[{"name":"tovar","num":"10","year":"2007"},{"name":"tovar","num":"10","year":"2007"}]
```

Comment: @Maxiiim задайте новый вопрос и приведите пример кода.